# why my http request work from postman and not from my angular application

Tags: java, angular, typescript

i have this function in my SpringBoot applican's controller

```
@GetMapping("/cancel/{orderID}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void cancelOrder(@PathVariable long orderID)
    {
        Order order = this.orderRepository.findOrderById(orderID);
        System.out.println(order);
        order.setStatus(OrderStatus.CANCELLED.name());
        this.orderService.cancel( order);
    }
```

i'm trying to access it from my angular application but it doesn't work , i tried it with postman and it works just fine

```
cancelOrder(orderId: Number) {
        return this.http.get(`${this.host}/orders/cancel/${orderId}`);
    }
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.setCancelStatus();
  }
setCancelStatus () {
  this.orderID =  parseInt(this.order.id);
  this.ecommerceService.cancelOrder(this.orderID);
  console.log(this.orderID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is the thing with `Observables`. You have to `subscribe` to them in order for the HTTP request to take flight.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.setCancelStatus();
  }
setCancelStatus () {
  this.orderID =  parseInt(this.order.id);
  // add subscribe here.
  this.ecommerceService.cancelOrder(this.orderID).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
  console.log(this.orderID);
}
```